# GDB - establish communication between gdb and OCD Deamon

Tags: gdb, daemon, gnu

I write OCD Daemon for an architecture that is not yet supported by already existing ones. As for now I try to establish remote communication between GDB <-> My_OCD_Daemon and here problems start. Right after I demand connection with my daemon by "target remote tcp:IP:PORT" gdb starts sending a bunch of requests, here are few of them:

Sending packet: $Hg0#df...Ack
Packet received:

Sending packet: $qxtn#cb...Ack

Packet received: XOCD

...

Sending packet: $qxtocdversion#99...Ack

Packet received: 6000

Sending packet: $p2b0#34...Ack

Reply contains invalid hex digit 79

Fetching next packet

...

For most of them it is enough if I reply just '+' which denotes successful reception. However there are commands like $p2b0#34 which expects some sane size value back.

So, is there a way to skip this never ending chain of requests from GDB and make it wait for user input?
How such init/hand-shake procedure shall look like?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so it looks like we can not "bypass" or "skip" this initial stage of gdb. It is used to configure gdb session and shall be conducted with care. Passing odd values to gdb will result in odd baheviour during debugging session.